# How do I get a sequence of cards in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

How can I take a sequence of ordered cards in haskel, for example, if I have this sequence

```
findSeq [(SIX,H),(SEVEN,H),(EIGHT,C),(NINE,H)]
```

I am using a function with explicit patterns which returns a single card as well. I know to use filter, but I cannot think of a way of doing it:D I want to display something like`

```
[(SIX,H),(SEVEN,H)]
```

Update: I have this now

```
findSeq::[Card]->[Card]
findSeq [] = []
findSeq (h:t)
|null t = [h]
|Just h==(pCard (head t) pack)=h:findSeq t
|otherwise=[h]
```

Comment: Do you want a random sequence or a specific sequence from `n` to `m`?

Comment: I want to move the first two cards which are in sequence, so those two should be returned, else, if the SEVEN is C, then nothing, because that would mean I have only 1 card, so no sequence. I can move them only from the begining, not from any other part of the list, so the head should pe on 0

Comment: you take the first two with `take 2 seq`. I don't understand the rest of your question and comment, you need to give a better explanation.

Comment: I am trying to see if the card on position 0 is the predecessor of the next one, if so, take it, and continue until I have a sequence of cards, else, return just []. So [(SIX,H),(SEVEN,H),(EIGHT,H),(NINE,C)] would return only the ordered sequence from the head, which is [(SIX,H),(SEVEN,H),(EIGHT,H)]

Comment: If I'm understanding your question now, you can use `Data.List.inits` to get all of the possible prefixes in your list and then filter that sequence based on whether or not the order is correct. Although I'm still not sure what order you're looking for here.

Comment: And how can I do that. I only want a filter to see if the card is the predecessor otf the next one, and if so, cons it to reminder and so on...

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how `zip cards (tails cards)` gives you a list of sequential pairs of cards form list `cards`.

Now you only need to `takeWhile` from this list, comparing your values and suits:

```
findSeq cards = takeWhile sameCards $ zip cards (tails cards) where
  sameCards (value1, suit1) (value2, suit2) = 
     suit1 == suit2 & value1 `precedes` value2
```

I suppose you have a function like `precedes` defined already.

Note: I don't have a Haskell compiler around at the moment; the code is untried.

Comment: See the function I am having so far. That one is returning me even the first element, if there is no sequence. How can I return nothing if there is no sequence of cards?

Comment: Also tried that findSeq lis@(h:(q:_))=takeWhile (sameCards h q) lis where
                      sameCards crd1 crd2= Just crd1==pCard crd2 pack, but apparently I get an error of too many arguments!